# Taking a Screenshot of Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas, screen-capture

I would like to take screenshot of webpages and let the users download as PNG files.
my code is working fine, but it is not capturing some image elements.

What am I doing wrong.

Here is the code

```
<!-- https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
function capture () {
  html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "ss.png";
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    a.click();
  });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Capture" onclick="capture()"/>
```

And the results from this code is this capture
[image]

But my website looks kind of like this, clearly you can see what is missing

[image]

Comment: are you waiting for `window::load`?

Comment: yes, I am @GrafiCode

Comment: Try to pass `{ useCORS: true }` as the second parameter of `html2canvas()`.

Comment: related to @Ivar comment: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/722

Comment: Hello @Ivar, I tried that too.... nothing much changed. I think it's capturing everything except image blocks.

Comment: @GrafiCode, You are right, it is missing the image elements

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is related to CORS issue.

To ensure it is a CORS issue you should check if you have any errors in your console mentioning CORS problem.

You should ensure that your images are either host in the same domain as your website. If not, you should ensure server where your images are loaded from is accepting CORS requests.

If it is CORS issue and server accept CORS request you can set option to html2canvas function as below :

```
html2canvas(el, {
   useCORS: true,
   allowTaint: true 
}).then(() => ...)
```

Please also ensure that you are loading your images with crossorigin attribute as below :

```
<img crossorigin src="...">
```